# How to remove sip-id after contacturi in contactheader in pjsip when using TLS

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I am able successfully register to my sip server using pjsip.
But when sending register from pjsip using tls transport,  there happens to be extra string attached to the contact header.

```
Contact: <sip:8888@192.168.1.14:57336;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000e922f243>"
```

Can somebody tell how to remove it from contact header??

This is my code.

```
    String sipURI = "sip:";
    String addTransport = "";
    if(enableTLS)
         addTransport = ";hide;transport=tls";
    String sipid = sipURI + username + "@" + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port;
    String registrar = sipURI + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port;
    String proxy = sipURI + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port+addTransport;

    AccountConfig accCfg = new AccountConfig();
    accCfg.setIdUri(sipid);

     AuthCredInfoVector creds = accCfg.getSipConfig().getAuthCreds();
    creds.clear();
    if (username.length() != 0) {
        creds.add(new AuthCredInfo("Digest", "*", username, 0, password));
    }
    StringVector proxies = accCfg.getSipConfig().getProxies();
    proxies.clear();

    if (proxy.length() != 0) {
        proxies.add(proxy);
    }
    accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri(registrar);
    accCfg.getRegConfig().setRetryIntervalSec(60);
    accCfg.getRegConfig().setTimeoutSec(60);
    accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(false);
 accCfg.getCallConfig().setTimerUse(pjsua_sip_timer_use.PJSUA_SIP_TIMER_INACTIVE);         accCfg.getCallConfig().setPrackUse(pjsua_100rel_use.PJSUA_100REL_NOT_USED);    
   app.addAcc(accCfg);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code for account registration?

Comment: @McLaLa added code

Comment: Tag android or pjsua2 next time you create a question :)

Comment: @McLaLa sure it is done

Comment: Why do you set registration uri twice?

Comment: @McLaLa when copied i pasted it twice sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151721/discussion-between-jeeva-and-mclala).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set the port in `TransportConfig` with `setPort(switch_port)`. There is no need to set id of uri with port or to create registrar string with port or to write proxy with port. This is enough, see code below.

```
TransportConfig sipTpConfig = new TransportConfig();
sipTpConfig.setPort(switch_port); 
...

String sipid = sipURI + username + "@" + switch_ip;
String registrar = sipURI + switch_ip;
String proxy = sipURI + switch_ip + addTransport;
...

accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri("sip:" + SIP_DOMAIN);
accCfg.getSipConfig().getProxies().add("sip:" + SIP_SERVER_HOST + ";hide");
```

Once again, set your port when you are setting up transport configuration. Another thing is if you have SRV-record configured on server side, let pjsip automatically detect available port. I mean, don't hard code port in register signal and don't set the port manually at all. Use this code instead to present correct contact header.

```
accCfg.getNatConfig().setContactRewriteUse(0);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setContactRewriteMethod(0);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setContactUseSrcPort(0);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setViaRewriteUse(0);
```

The `SIP_DOMAIN` is your domain, `switch_ip`, everything before "@" and `SIP_SERVER_HOST` is your outbound proxy.

Comment: srv recordis not enabled in my server

Comment: yes i always do that .transport config is in another block so i didnt mention it sorry.

Comment: my sip proxy listens only one particular port and other ports are blocked but wil give a try .

Comment: i use the same code for creating udp transport but i dont get extra words in contact parameter

Comment: Does this return something in your case with TLS `accCfg .getRegConfig().getContactParams();`? If yes, try to set it to an empty string.